# Can't get floats to match 100% width or expand parent

Tags: html, css

I have some basic CSS which im trying to make a post layout for a forum but i cannot get it to work.

I have one div 100% width with two floats below it side by side. They seem to never equal 100% width and so don't line up with properly.

Equally the parent div of the two floats does not expand if the floats expand and i do not know how to fix it.

This is what i have so far:

CSS

```
.parent{
    width: 100%;
    top: 10px;
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    color: black;
}
.line{
    height:20px;
    padding-left:10px;
    lineHeight: 20px;
    margin:0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.container{
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom:1px solid red;
}
.fleft{
    float:left;
    width:10%;
    text-align:left;
    margin:0px;
    padding-left:10px;
    border-right:1px solid black;
}
.fleft2{
    float:left;
    width:86%;
    text-align:left;
    margin:0px;
    padding-left:10px;    
    border-right:1px solid black;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="parent">

    <div class="line">

        <span style="float:left;">Test</span>
        <span style="float:right;">Test 2</span>

    </div>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="fleft"> Hello </div>
        <div class="fleft2"> Hello Message</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS Fiddle also provided:

http://jsfiddle.net/yMaqR/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have one div 100% width with two floats below it side by side. They seem to never equal 100% width and so don't line up with properly.

You have to take into consideration the padding & margin. So if you add up width + padding + margin of the floated elements and they overflow the width of the parent, they'll be wrapped.
So a possible solution is to remove the padding and add it maybe to child elements.

> Equally the parent div of the two floats does not expand if the floats expand and i do not know how to fix it.

The solution is to use a [clearfix](http://themergency.com/css-clearfix-demystified/)

More [about floats](http://complexspiral.com/publications/containing-floats/) and understanding how they work.

Comment: I found a solution so it does not take the padding and margin into account as a seperate sum of the width:
http://jsfiddle.net/yMaqR/23/  credit goes to Paul Irish.